# How to turn off debug log messages in spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, log4j

I read in spring boot docs (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html)

> you can also specify debug=true in your application.properties"

So I guess I can turn off the debug logs by adding debug=false in application.properties. I did it but unfortunately, it didn't work. Then I read in the same doc

> The logging system is initialized early in the application lifecycle and as such logging properties will not be found in property files loaded via `@PropertySource` annotations"

and

> "Since logging is initialized before the `ApplicationContext` is created, it isn’t possible to control logging from `@PropertySources` in Spring `@Configuration` files"

and

> "When possible we recommend that you use the -spring variants for your logging configuration" so I added a file named `log4j-spring.properties` in `src/main/resources`.

In such file, I added `debug=false` (only this line and nothing else) but I am still seeing all "current date" [main] DEBUG ... messages. So, my question is how can I turn off the debug messages in my Spring Boot Application as I will deploy to the application to production. Is there a recommended way to reach this via maven?

**Added in Feb 12th**

The two main methods:
1)By using AnnotationConfigApplicationContext:

```
public class DemoAppNoBoot {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
              AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(
                           BatchConfiguration.class);
              JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
              Job job = (Job) context.getBean("job");
               try {
                     JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(job, new JobParameters());
              } catch (Exception e) {
                     e.printStackTrace();
              }
       }
}
```

Snippet output:

```
08:26:18.713 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemProperties] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:26:18.744 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Adding [systemEnvironment] PropertySource with lowest search precedence
08:26:18.744 [main] DEBUG o.s.core.env.StandardEnvironment - Initialized StandardEnvironment with PropertySources [systemProperties,systemEnvironment]
08:26:18.947 [main] INFO  o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@532760d8: startup date [Fri Feb 12 08:26:18 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
08:26:18.947 [main] DEBUG o.s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext - Bean factory for org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@532760d8: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@50b494a6: defining beans [org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerProcessor,org.springframework.context.event.internalEventListenerFactory,batchConfiguration]; root of factory hierarchy
08:26:18.979 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 
...
08:26:32.560 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'lifecycleProcessor'
08:26:32.560 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor'
08:26:32.560 [main] DEBUG o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Returning cached instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindingPostProcessor'
08:26:32.560 [main] DEBUG o.s.s.a.ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor - Could not find default TaskScheduler bean
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.springframework.scheduling.TaskScheduler] is defined     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:372) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]      at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:332) ~[spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
...
08:26:33.529 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL update
08:26:33.529 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - Executing prepared SQL statement [UPDATE BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION set START_TIME = ?, END_TIME = ?,  STATUS = ?, EXIT_CODE = ?, EXIT_MESSAGE = ?, VERSION = ?, CREATE_TIME = ?, LAST_UPDATED = ? where JOB_EXECUTION_ID = ? and VERSION = ?]
08:26:33.529 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate - SQL update affected 1 rows
08:26:33.545 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Initiating transaction commit
08:26:33.545 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Committing JDBC transaction on Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@33bbce9c]
08:26:33.545 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.j.d.DataSourceTransactionManager - Releasing JDBC Connection [org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection@33bbce9c] after transaction
08:26:33.545 [pool-1-thread-1] DEBUG o.s.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils - Returning JDBC Connection to DataSource
08:26:33.545 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher - Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
```

2. Main method with SpringApplication.run

   @SpringBootApplication
   public class DemoApplication {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   SpringApplication.run(BatchConfiguration.class, args);
   }
   }

Entire output:

```
: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.1.RELEASE)
2016-02-12 08:02:36.145  INFO 12172 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Starting DemoApplication on GH-VDIKCISV252 with PID 12172 (C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\demo\target\classes started by e049447 in C:\STS\wsRestTemplate\demo)
2016-02-12 08:02:36.145  INFO 12172 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-02-12 08:02:36.473  INFO 12172 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@4e4aea35: startup date [Fri Feb 12 08:02:36 CST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-02-12 08:02:42.176  WARN 12172 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.stepScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2016-02-12 08:02:42.349  WARN 12172 --- [           main] o.s.c.a.ConfigurationClassEnhancer       : @Bean method ScopeConfiguration.jobScope is non-static and returns an object assignable to Spring's BeanFactoryPostProcessor interface. This will result in a failure to process annotations such as @Autowired, @Resource and @PostConstruct within the method's declaring @Configuration class. Add the 'static' modifier to this method to avoid these container lifecycle issues; see @Bean javadoc for complete details.
2016-02-12 08:02:42.724  INFO 12172 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:hsqldb:mem:testdb', username='sa'
2016-02-12 08:02:43.802  WARN 12172 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.AbstractListenerFactoryBean    : org.springframework.batch.item.ItemReader is an interface.  The implementing class will not be queried for annotation based listener configurations.  If using @StepScope on a @Bean method, be sure to return the implementing class so listner annotations can be used.
2016-02-12 08:02:44.990  INFO 12172 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executing SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql]
2016-02-12 08:02:45.179  INFO 12172 --- [           main] o.s.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils     : Executed SQL script from class path resource [org/springframework/batch/core/schema-hsqldb.sql] in 189 ms.
2016-02-12 08:02:46.804  INFO 12172 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-02-12 08:02:46.868  INFO 12172 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherCommandLineRunner   : Running default command line with: []
2016-02-12 08:02:46.962  INFO 12172 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
2016-02-12 08:02:47.040  INFO 12172 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.c.r.s.JobRepositoryFactoryBean     : No database type set, using meta data indicating: HSQL
2016-02-12 08:02:47.243  INFO 12172 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2016-02-12 08:02:47.259  INFO 12172 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : No TaskExecutor has been set, defaulting to synchronous executor.
2016-02-12 08:02:47.321  INFO 12172 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}]
2016-02-12 08:02:47.368  INFO 12172 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
2016-02-12 08:02:47.400  INFO 12172 --- [           main] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - collecting the MYAPP2 out file names
2016-02-12 08:02:47.525  INFO 12172 --- [           main] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - no file found
2016-02-12 08:02:47.556  INFO 12172 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=1}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
2016-02-12 08:02:47.556  INFO 12172 --- [           main] com.example.DemoApplication              : Started DemoApplication in 12.1 seconds (JVM running for 13.405)
2016-02-12 08:02:47.556  INFO 12172 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] launched with the following parameters: [{}]
2016-02-12 08:02:47.618  INFO 12172 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [step1]
2016-02-12 08:02:47.634  INFO 12172 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - collecting the MYAPP2 out file names
2016-02-12 08:02:47.634  INFO 12172 --- [pool-2-thread-1] com.example.CustomItemReader             : read method - no file found
2016-02-12 08:02:47.650  INFO 12172 --- [pool-2-thread-1] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=job1]] completed with the following parameters: [{}] and the following status: [COMPLETED]
```

BatchConfiguration class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("com.example")
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
@PropertySource("config.properties")
public class BatchConfiguration {
       @Autowired
       private JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
       @Autowired
       private StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
       @Bean
       public Step step1(ItemReader<String> reader,
                     ItemProcessor<String, String> processor, ItemWriter<String> writer) {
              return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1").<String, String> chunk(1)                          .reader(reader).processor(processor).writer(writer)
                           .allowStartIfComplete(true).build();
       }
//I took out the rest of BatchConfiguration class
```

Application.properties (only one line)

```
logging.level.*=OFF
```

P.S. I will not show config.properties because it only contains several property names with path settup used in business logic

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.example</groupId>
       <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <packaging>jar</packaging>
       <name>demo</name>
       <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
       <parent>
              <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
              <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
              <version>1.3.1.RELEASE</version>
              <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
       </parent>
       <properties>
              <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
              <java.version>1.8</java.version>
              <spring.batch.version>3.0.6.RELEASE</spring.batch.version>
       </properties>
       <dependencies>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
              </dependency>
              <dependency>
                     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                     <scope>test</scope>
              </dependency>
       </dependencies>
       <build>
              <plugins>
                     <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                           <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                     </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                           <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                           <configuration>
                                  <archive>
                                         <manifest>
                                                <mainClass>com.example.DemoAppNoBoot</mainClass>
                                         </manifest>
                                  </archive>
                                  <descriptorRefs>
                                         <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                                  </descriptorRefs>
                           </configuration>
                           <executions>
                                  <execution>
                                         <phase>install</phase>
                                         <goals>
                                                <goal>single</goal>
                                         </goals>
                                  </execution>
                           </executions>
                     </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                           <version>2.5.1</version>
                           <configuration>
                                  <goals>install</goals>
                                  <preparationGoals>install</preparationGoals>
                           </configuration>
                     </plugin>
                     <plugin>
                           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                           <configuration>
                                  <archive>
                                         <manifest>
                                                <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                                <mainClass>com.example.DemoAppNoBoot</mainClass>
                                         </manifest>
                                  </archive>
                           </configuration>
                     </plugin>
              </plugins>
       </build>
</project>
```

Maven Dependencies (the relevant ones for my doubt):

```
logback-classic-1.1.3.jar
logback-core-1.1.3.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar
log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.13.jar
```

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels. Basically add `logging.level.org.springframework=INFO` should do the trick or `logging.level.root=INFO`.

Comment: In its default configuration, Spring Boot will not output any debug log messages. What logging-related configuration have you added to your application?

Comment: Please see the maven dependencies above: what is effectively been used? logback or log4j? I understand logback is been used or at least it is most relevant library for logging since docs states "By default, If you use the ‘Starter POM’, Logback will be used for logging." Supposing I want to change the place where the outputs will be printed in production (Unix). Which file name must I add: logback-spring.xml or log4j-spring.properties in order to edit LOG_FILE and LOG_PATH? I based my question on "other properties are transferred from the Spring Environment to System properties" statement.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

In application.properties you can add ‘logging.level.*=LEVEL’ where ‘LEVEL’ is one of TRACE, DEBUG, INFO, WARN, ERROR, FATAL, OFF. * is responsible for package/class.

For example

```
logging.level.root=WARN
logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate=ERROR
```

This means that root logger has WARN level.
org.springframework.web is on  DEBUG level, but all hibernates files are logged only ERROR.

In your case you must set logging.level.root on one of level from INFO, WARN, ERROR,FATAL or OFF to turn off all logging.

See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-custom-log-levels

Comment: I think it's worth noting that none of this should be necessary to avoid having any debug log output. Spring Boot's default log level is info.

Comment: I thought that, since I added the spring boot libraries and I added @EnableAutoConfiguration in BatchConfiguration class, I was using spring boot regardless if I started the application throw (1) "AnnotationConfigApplicationContext ... jobLauncher.run" or (2) "@SpringBootApplication ... SpringApplication.run...". I am assuming that I was wrong. I will only effectively use Spring Boot if I start via option 2. Please, correct me if I am wrong. So, why if I change logging.level.*=DEBUG in Application.properties it changes nothing in output when I call the option main method?

Answer (score 10):

While using Spring Rest Docs with SpringMockMVC with testLogging.showStandardStreams set to true in Gradle, Spring cluttered the console with info & debug logs. I had to use [Mkyong's solution](https://www.mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-test-how-to-stop-debug-logs/) where in a logback-test.xml in src/test/resources needs to be created on top of the chosen solution here. Use log-level OFF, ERROR, WARN, DEBUG

logback-test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="ERROR"/>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but it will mess up the entire spring boot configuration in application.properties just to get rid of the initial verbose :S

Answer (score 2):

Simply add these two lines to you app main:

```
Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
root.setLevel(Level.ERROR);
```

The necessary import are:

```
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Level;
import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
```

Answer (score 1):

in addition to a log4j.properties or log4j.xml file you will need all three of these entries in your maven pom.xml... adding the log4j-acl artifact instantly fixed the problem for me. it routes apache-commons-logging entries from commons logging over to log4j

I'm not sure how you would go about this in grunt but the bridge is what you need.

```
    <!-- Log4J -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-jcl</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

I am using XML configured Log4j2 and Spring Boot. For me, I needed to specify the `logging` subpackage also, so inside the `<Loggers>` block:

> ```
>     <Logger name="org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.logging" level="error" />
> ```

Answer (score -9):

Click Breakpoints icon and untick checkBox. After Done Re-Run again

Comment: I don't see how this is related to the question.

Comment: How can I change this commend and relate to this question? Brother

Comment: This does not answer the question