# turn off debug logging spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, junit4, maven-surefire-plugin

## Issue

I want to turn off the debug output on the console for my spring boot application.
I expected to have a default INFO logging. But that is not the case.
I tried to turn the levels off brute force with
https://mkyong.com/spring-boot/spring-boot-log4j-2-example/
I dont like this a currently it does not even work.
In [how turn off debug log messages in spring boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353869/how-turn-off-debug-log-messages-in-spring-boot) this is marked as a solution. I dont think it is.
I reduced my project to the minimum and get this Error for multiple kind of setups.
Initially i tried to use Spring Boot 2.2.1.RELEASE with Jupiter and Log4J2. With Log4J i was able to reduce the logging but i had to set each Logger individually. The hierarchy did not seem to work.
Here I present Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE with Junit4 and default logging (should be logback).

## pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <spring-boot.version>2.1.1.RELEASE</spring-boot.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.2</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
                <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

## my code

### TestClazz.java

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class TestClazz {
    @Test
    public void testSomething() {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

### TestSpringBootApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class TestSpringBootApplication {
}
```

## my configuration

### application.properties

```
logging.level.org.springframework=OFF
logging.level.root=OFF
```

### logback-test.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <include resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/base.xml" />
    <logger name="org.springframework" level="OFF"/>
</configuration>
```

## project structure

[image]

## console output

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.fee:fdsg:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 30, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] ----------------------------< com.fee:fdsg >----------------------------
[INFO] Building fdsg 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
.....
[INFO] Compiling 2 source files to [[CENSORED]]]\fdsg\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.2:test (default-test) @ fdsg ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running any.TestClazz
2020-04-06 22:18:07.802 DEBUG 14616 --- [           main] .c.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application started with classpath: [file:/C:/winapp/cygwin304/tmp/surefire101039361747353203/surefirebooter234714427829446725.jar]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.1.RELEASE)

2020-04-06 22:18:07.863 DEBUG 14616 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Loading source class any.TestSpringBootApplication
2020-04-06 22:18:07.877 DEBUG 14616 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file '[[CENSORED]]]/fdsg/target/classes/application.properties' (classpath:/application.properties)
2020-04-06 22:18:08.241 DEBUG 14616 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 


============================
CONDITIONS EVALUATION REPORT
============================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   GenericCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.GenericCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   NoOpCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.NoOpCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   SimpleCacheConfiguration matched:
      - Cache org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.SimpleCacheConfiguration automatic cache type (CacheCondition)

   TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor' (OnClassCondition)

   TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration#applicationTaskExecutor matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: java.util.concurrent.Executor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TaskExecutionAutoConfiguration#taskExecutorBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.task.TaskExecutorBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)

   TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration matched:
      - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler' (OnClassCondition)

   TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration#taskSchedulerBuilder matched:
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.task.TaskSchedulerBuilder; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   ActiveMQAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect' (OnClassCondition)

   ArtemisAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.jms.ConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   BatchAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher' (OnClassCondition)

   CacheAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport (OnBeanCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   CacheAutoConfiguration.CacheManagerJpaDependencyConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean' (OnClassCondition)
         - Ancestor org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.cache.CacheAutoConfiguration did not match (ConditionEvaluationReport.AncestorsMatchedCondition)

   CaffeineCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.github.benmanes.caffeine.cache.Caffeine', 'org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraReactiveDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.datastax.driver.core.Cluster' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.cassandra.ReactiveSession' (OnClassCondition)

   CassandraRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.datastax.driver.core.Session' (OnClassCondition)

   ClientHttpConnectorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient' (OnClassCondition)
....


   HazelcastCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance', 'com.hazelcast.spring.cache.HazelcastCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   HazelcastJpaDependencyAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.hazelcast.core.HazelcastInstance' (OnClassCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.persistence.EntityManager' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpEncodingAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpHandlerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.server.reactive.HttpHandler' (OnClassCondition)

   HttpMessageConvertersAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageConverter' (OnClassCondition)

   HypermediaAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.hateoas.Resource' (OnClassCondition)

   InfinispanCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.infinispan.spring.provider.SpringEmbeddedCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   InfluxDbAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.influxdb.InfluxDB' (OnClassCondition)

   IntegrationAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration' (OnClassCondition)

   JCacheCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required classes 'javax.cache.Caching', 'org.springframework.cache.jcache.JCacheCacheManager' (OnClassCondition)

   JacksonAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper' (OnClassCondition)

   JdbcRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.jdbc.repository.config.JdbcConfiguration' (OnClassCondition)

   JdbcTemplateAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   JerseyAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.servlet.ServletRegistration' (OnClassCondition)

   JestAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'io.searchbox.client.JestClient' (OnClassCondition)

   JmsAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.jms.Message' (OnClassCondition)

   JmxAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.jmx.enabled=true) found different value in property 'enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)
      Matched:
         - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter' (OnClassCondition)

   JndiConnectionFactoryAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   JndiDataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType' (OnClassCondition)

   JooqAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.jooq.DSLContext' (OnClassCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   JsonbAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.json.bind.Jsonb' (OnClassCondition)

   JtaAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.Transaction' (OnClassCondition)

   KafkaAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   LdapAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.ldap.core.ContextSource' (OnClassCondition)

   LdapRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.ldap.repository.LdapRepository' (OnClassCondition)

   LiquibaseAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'liquibase.change.DatabaseChange' (OnClassCondition)

   MailSenderAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage' (OnClassCondition)

   MailSenderValidatorAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnSingleCandidate did not find required type 'org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl' (OnBeanCondition)

   MessageSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - ResourceBundle did not find bundle with basename messages (MessageSourceAutoConfiguration.ResourceBundleCondition)

   MongoAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.client.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoReactiveAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoReactiveDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoReactiveRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.mongodb.MongoClient' (OnClassCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement' (OnClassCondition)

   MustacheAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.samskivert.mustache.Mustache' (OnClassCondition)

   Neo4jDataAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   Neo4jRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession' (OnClassCondition)

   OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity' (OnClassCondition)

   OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken' (OnClassCondition)

   PersistenceExceptionTranslationAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor' (OnClassCondition)

   ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration#buildProperties:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnResource did not find resource '${spring.info.build.location:classpath:META-INF/build-info.properties}' (OnResourceCondition)

   ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration#gitProperties:
      Did not match:
         - GitResource did not find git info at classpath:git.properties (ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration.GitResourceAvailableCondition)

   QuartzAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.quartz.Scheduler' (OnClassCondition)

   RabbitAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.rabbitmq.client.Channel' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveOAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveOAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveSecurityAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveUserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.ReactiveAuthenticationManager' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactiveWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.http.ReactiveHttpInputMessage' (OnClassCondition)

   ReactorCoreAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisOperations' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisCacheConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisReactiveAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'reactor.core.publisher.Flux' (OnClassCondition)

   RedisRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.redis.repository.configuration.EnableRedisRepositories' (OnClassCondition)

   RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.rest.webmvc.config.RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration' (OnClassCondition)

   RestClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient' (OnClassCondition)

   RestTemplateAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate' (OnClassCondition)

   SecurityAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.DefaultAuthenticationEventPublisher' (OnClassCondition)

   SecurityFilterAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.config.http.SessionCreationPolicy' (OnClassCondition)

   SecurityRequestMatcherProviderAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.RequestMatcher' (OnClassCondition)

   SendGridAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'com.sendgrid.SendGrid' (OnClassCondition)

   ServletWebServerFactoryAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.servlet.ServletRequest' (OnClassCondition)

   SessionAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.session.Session' (OnClassCondition)

   SolrAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CloudSolrClient' (OnClassCondition)

   SolrRepositoriesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient' (OnClassCondition)

   SpringApplicationAdminJmxAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnProperty (spring.application.admin.enabled=true) did not find property 'enabled' (OnPropertyCondition)

   SpringDataWebAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.data.web.PageableHandlerMethodArgumentResolver' (OnClassCondition)

   TaskSchedulingAutoConfiguration#taskScheduler:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnBean (names: org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans named org.springframework.context.annotation.internalScheduledAnnotationProcessor (OnBeanCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.thymeleaf.templatemode.TemplateMode' (OnClassCondition)

   TransactionAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)

   UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' (OnClassCondition)

   ValidationAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.validation.executable.ExecutableValidator' (OnClassCondition)

   WebClientAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClient' (OnClassCondition)

   WebFluxAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.reactive.config.WebFluxConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.servlet.Servlet' (OnClassCondition)

   WebServiceTemplateAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.oxm.Marshaller' (OnClassCondition)

   WebServicesAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketMessagingAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketReactiveAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.servlet.Servlet' (OnClassCondition)

   WebSocketServletAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.servlet.Servlet' (OnClassCondition)

   XADataSourceAutoConfiguration:
      Did not match:
         - @ConditionalOnClass did not find required class 'javax.transaction.TransactionManager' (OnClassCondition)


Exclusions:
-----------

    None


Unconditional classes:
----------------------

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration

    org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration



hi
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.214 s - in any.TestClazz
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
.......
```

Comment: Can you share your project in a public repo? Or something reproducing the error

Comment: the description shows the complete source code. Anyway i might set up repo for this. Will let you know when i did.

Comment: btw it works with a thresholdfilter for my consoleAppender but this is just a workaround

Comment: Could you may be share a github project ?

Comment: It's not obvious from your question if you're running your test through an IDE or at the command line. What happens when you run using `mvn clean test -Dtest=TestClazz` in a terminal? When you run the test, do you see that your test logback config is copied to `target/test-classes/logback-test.xml`?

Answer (score 0):

To enable logs till `INFO` and not log messages with levels `DEBUG` and `TRACE` this should suffice:

```
logging.level.root=INFO
```

the `logging.level.*` should have one of the following values: `ERROR`, `WARN`, `INFO`, `DEBUG`, or `TRACE`. You can refer to the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-logging).

If you specify a particular level, all levels are enabled starting from `ERROR` till that level. For instance, setting `logging.level.root=INFO` will log `ERROR`, `WARN`, and `INFO` messages.